# Make custom resizing events logic

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I have been working with full calendar and most of the features I need have been built in. But the last thing I want to add I have very little idea how to approach.

Note: I am only working in agenda week view and no others

What I want:
Much like the all day events I would like to drag normal events with start and end times sideways. So on mouse down on one of the sides it would be possible to resize sideways along days. And on mouse up the days that the event was over would become new events with the same variables as the original with the exception of the day.

How I think I could do it:
I think I could treat the resized event as droppable events and when released would just go through the eventReceive function I already made but I don't know how to start going about doing that or if there is an easier way.

Edit: ok I explained a lot of what I want and not where I am facing problems. I do not know how to add custom resizing logic to my calendar. There have been posts that set the CSS width of events but I feel it would be unrealistic to reset that everytime the mouse moves especially knowing that fullcalendar uses the jquery-ui already for resizing. So my question is: Is there a way to add that logic to events in the initializing of the calendarand if so how?

Comment: Please edit your post and include some example code or code that you have tried. Please include any console errors you might see. Members of Stack Overflow are here to help assist with your code not write it for you.

Comment: I don't think it's possible without a re-write of the internals. What you're describing are repeating events. It might be easier to handle a click on the event and expose some custom UI (.e.g like Outlook or Google Calendar does) where the user can define some parameters (e.g. how long to repeat for, how frequently) and when they press OK it generates the events accordingly. A little bit less user-friendly (although some might appreciate a greater level of control) but a lot easier to achieve.